# Can't start SQL services

Tags: sql-server

I am having issues starting my SQL services. Currently it is failing the start due to:

> FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot
>   find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file
>   'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf'. Diagnose and
>   correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.

The issue herein lies in the fact that this .ldf file is not on the E drive. There is no E: drive. The file is located on the F: drive.

I cannot find anywhere to tell SQL to change this. I can not drop/move/detach/etc the databases, because I can't even get the service to start, in order to connect.

This is happening on 3 different instances of SQL, after volume moves. Any ideas?

SQL 2008

Comment: Are there any messages in the error log pertaining to the `master` database?

Answer (score 6):

Go to Command Prompt and Try Start Service With This

```
NET START MSSQLServer /f /T3608
```

Then in Command Prompt Login With SQLcMD

```
SQLCMD -E  -S ServerName
```

Then run Following Command to move the model log to the F drive.  Make sure the path is correct.

```
ALTER DATABASE Model MODIFY FILE( NAME = modellog , FILENAME = 'F:Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf' )
Go
```

Then stop and re-start your instance.

Repeat with other files if needed.  Except master.  That is a whole different problem.

Comment: or try `SQLCMD -A` to use the DAC since this would be in single user mode.

Comment: remember, you should use NET STOP to stop the instance instead of the configuration mgr if you use NET START